# How can I get the instance of an object that is determined in the class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class that has structure containing other classes, each of these classes also may contain different classes. So this is tree structure of classes.

```
public class FirstLevelClass {
   public SecondLevelClass1 secondLevelClass1;
   public SecondLevelClass2 secondLevelClass2;
   ...
}

public class SecondLevelClass1 {
   public ThirdLevelClass thirdLevelClass;
   public String fieldSecondLevelClass;
   ...
}
```

I have initialized variable of FirstLevelClass.

```
FirstLevelClass firstLevelClass;
```

I need to get instance of secondLevelClass1 that is stored inside firstLevelClass. How can I do that having a name of the class SecondLevelClass1?

Basically I need to get value of the field inside SecondLevelClass1. But I failed when wrote this:

```
String fieldName = "fieldSecondLevelClass";
Field[] fields = firstLevelClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
Object foundValue = null;

for (Field field : fields) {
   Field foundField = null;
   foundField = field.getType().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
   foundValue = fieldSecondLevelClass.get((Class.forName(foundField.getDeclaringClass().getName())).newInstance());
}
```

Because the instance that I call fieldSecondLevelClass.get(...) with isnt initialized. But if i write

```
foundValue = foundField.get(((FirstLevelClass) firstLevelClass).secondLevelClass1);
```

it will work fine.
So, do any of you ideas how can I pass right instance of secondLevelClass1 using the name of it and instance of FirstLevelClass to fieldSecondLevelClass.get(...)?

Comment: Call me crazy but...why are you trying to do this through reflection instead of providing a getter for the field(s) you're interested in?

Comment: If the field isn't initialized, there *is* no "right instance".

Comment: 2JonK yeah I might, but it is challenge for me to solve problem this way

Comment: 2JonK and there is requirement to develop this code functioning for any class

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do, but I will attempt to simplify this for you.

First, your fields are declared public.  And even if they were not, you could expose getters/accessors, so there is no reason for reflections.

It's also a red flag to me that you have a class for first level, another class for second level, and a third class for third level.  I suppose it depends on how much these types vary in their interface.  If this tree needs to go any deeper than 3 levels, I suggest abstracting these out into a generic `Node` class which has references to its children and you can nest them in any order.

```
public class Node {
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(Node c) {
       children.add(c);
    }

    public Node[] getChildren() {
        return children.toArray(new Node[0]);
    }
}

public class SomethingElse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node firstLevel = new Node();
        Node secondLevel = new Node();
        secondLevel.addChild(new Node());
        firstLevel.addChild(secondLevel);
    }
}
```

This would be much easier to work with.  However, the design cost is that it forces all nodes at all tree depths to have identical behavior.  If that is not desired, then this may not work well for you.

Comment: Thank you for answer! The reason why I have such complicated tree of classes is my limitation on data wich I need to process. Data structure is defined via json and is represented via tree too. In order to fill objects in java I use gson library. It makes the process simple if structure of object is the same with structure of json representation. So i've been limited by this requirment. And class on each level is unique, so gson conversion of structure you sugested unfortunately wont work. Thanks anyway!